# Can I upgrade MacOS X 10.4 to 10.7 Lion?

Tags: macos

I want to upgrade my OS to a new level so that I can download Google Chrome. My computer is pretty old and is running Version 10.4.11. The Mac store won't let me download Lion because I need a higher version than I already have. Where can I find that intermediate version so that I can then upgrade to Lion?

Comment: So you have a PPC machine? Lion is Intel only.

Comment: Processor says 1.83 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can buy [Snow Leopard](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573Z/A) in the online [Apple Store](http://store.apple.com/), install it and then upgrade to Lion via the Mac App Store.

Comment: Thank you! Do I have to order Snow Leopard by mail or is there a way to download it?

Comment: Order by mail (or visit an Apple Retail Store if available in your area)

Answer (score 0):

Are you a MobileMe user? Then chances are that you get a [free upgrade](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2012/04/free-snow-leopard-dvd-to-push-mobileme-users-to-migrate-to-icloud.html) to Snow Leopard...